# Quartz Scheduler stops working after some time

Tags: multithreading, quartz-scheduler

We are using Quartz (with the spring) to trigger few tasks. This set up was working for so many years without any issues. Recently, the scheduler stopped working all of a sudden. After server restart it works fine, however stops working again after some time. Can some one help me resolve this?

Below are the version details for your reference:

```
Windows Server: 2003 
Quartz: 1.5.1 
Spring: 3.2.2
```

I generated thread dump to check if every thing is ok. It looks fine. Below is the part of thread dump pertaining to Quartz threads.

```
"QuartzScheduler_QuartzScheduler-NON_CLUSTERED_MisfireHandler" daemon prio=6 tid=0x57c26400 nid=0x270 runnable [0x58ecf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:971)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:941)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:432)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:181)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.execute_for_describe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:420)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute_maybe_describe(OracleStatement.java:896)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.execute_maybe_describe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:452)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:986)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2888)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2929)
    - locked <0x10a0f020> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement)
    - locked <0x10f39060> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.obtainLock(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:137)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.doRecoverMisfires(JobStoreCMT.java:1298)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:2409)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.run(JobStoreSupport.java:2428)


"QuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" prio=6 tid=0x57bfc400 nid=0x1334 runnable [0x58e1f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:971)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:941)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:432)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:181)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.execute_for_describe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:420)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute_maybe_describe(OracleStatement.java:896)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.execute_maybe_describe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:452)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:986)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2888)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2929)
    - locked <0x10a0f358> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement)
    - locked <0x10f391c8> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.obtainLock(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:137)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreCMT.java:1134)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:233)

"QuartzScheduler_Worker-9" prio=6 tid=0x57c75400 nid=0x794 in Object.wait() [0x58d6f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.getNextRunnable(SimpleThreadPool.java:428)
    - locked <0x0ec94410> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.access$000(SimpleThreadPool.java:47)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:518)

"QuartzScheduler_Worker-8" prio=6 tid=0x57c73c00 nid=0x1aa4 in Object.wait() [0x58cbf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.getNextRunnable(SimpleThreadPool.java:428)
    - locked <0x0ec94410> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.access$000(SimpleThreadPool.java:47)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:518)

"QuartzScheduler_Worker-7" prio=6 tid=0x57c79400 nid=0xfec in Object.wait() [0x58c0f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.getNextRunnable(SimpleThreadPool.java:428)
    - locked <0x0ec94410> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.access$000(SimpleThreadPool.java:47)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:518)

"QuartzScheduler_Worker-6" prio=6 tid=0x57c77c00 nid=0x650 in Object.wait() [0x58b5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.getNextRunnable(SimpleThreadPool.java:428)
    - locked <0x0ec94410> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.access$000(SimpleThreadPool.java:47)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:518)

"QuartzScheduler_Worker-5" prio=6 tid=0x57c69400 nid=0x8cc in Object.wait() [0x58aaf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.getNextRunnable(SimpleThreadPool.java:428)
    - locked <0x0ec94410> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.access$000(SimpleThreadPool.java:47)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:518)

"QuartzScheduler_Worker-4" prio=6 tid=0x57c68000 nid=0x338 in Object.wait() [0x589ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.getNextRunnable(SimpleThreadPool.java:428)
    - locked <0x0ec94410> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.access$000(SimpleThreadPool.java:47)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:518)

"QuartzScheduler_Worker-3" prio=6 tid=0x57c62800 nid=0x178c in Object.wait() [0x5894f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.getNextRunnable(SimpleThreadPool.java:428)
    - locked <0x0ec94410> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.access$000(SimpleThreadPool.java:47)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:518)

"QuartzScheduler_Worker-2" prio=6 tid=0x57c72400 nid=0x1e8c in Object.wait() [0x5889f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.getNextRunnable(SimpleThreadPool.java:428)
    - locked <0x0ec94410> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.access$000(SimpleThreadPool.java:47)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:518)

"QuartzScheduler_Worker-1" prio=6 tid=0x57c56400 nid=0x11bc in Object.wait() [0x587ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.getNextRunnable(SimpleThreadPool.java:428)
    - locked <0x0ec94410> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.access$000(SimpleThreadPool.java:47)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:518)

"QuartzScheduler_Worker-0" prio=6 tid=0x57c36000 nid=0x1770 in Object.wait() [0x5873f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.getNextRunnable(SimpleThreadPool.java:428)
    - locked <0x0ec94410> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.access$000(SimpleThreadPool.java:47)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:518)
```